# How to invert a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which prints out the winner of my game. I want to do the same but with the loser, but I can't get quite the result i want with the code I wrote, it prints out false instead of the other player. I already have outside another function which switches between player when there is a click on the game.

```
function winner() {
        isWinningState = true;
        $("#winner").css({
            visibility: "visible",
        });
        var won = $(
            "<div id='currentPlayer'>" +
                "<p>" +
                currentPlayer +
                " won!" +
                "</p>" +
                "</div>"
        );
        var b = !currentPlayer;
        var lost = $(
            "<div id='currentPlayer'>" +
                "<p>" +
                b +
                " lost!" +
                "</p>" +
                "</div>"
        );

        $("#winner").append(won);
        $("#winner").append(lost);
        $(".again").on("click", function () {
            won.remove();
            lost.remove();
        });
    }
```

Comment: what is currentPlayer, a string?

Comment: Yes, var currentPlayer = "player1". And then I have this to switch between player: 

function switchPlayer() {
        if (currentPlayer === "player1") {
            currentPlayer = "player2";
        } else if (currentPlayer === "player2") {
            currentPlayer = "player1";
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same logic you used to toggle `currentPlayer` string. The `!` operator works on booleans... Not on strings. So you need an `if` statement...

Below, it is written on one line using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var b = (currentPlayer === "player1") ? "player2" : "player1";
```

That is:

```
var variableName = (condition) ? "value if true" : "value if false";
```

Comment: I just tried your code but it seems it's not printing anything. Even though the logic works

Comment: Hey... Look `$("#winner").append(won); $("#winner").append(lost);` It is `#winner` in both cases... I suppose it should be something like `$("#looser").append(lost);`. It is up to you to debug that.